# Изображения слайдера slick-slider во всю высоту экрана

Tags: javascript, css, css3, slider

Использую простой слайдер:
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#demos

Надо чтобы слайды растягивались на всю высоту экрана браузера(на разных разрешениях.)

Задал так:

```
  .slick-slide img {  
    object-fit: cover;
    max-height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: block;
    width:100%;
  }
```

И для контейнера:

```
.header-slide {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Если просто эта картинка, то все работает:
А с подключенным слайдером не растягивается до всей высоты окна:
Возможен ли какой-то вариант решения?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, если кому надо:

```
.slider .slick-slide {
  height: 100vh;
}

.slide img {
  height: inherit;
}
```